# What is wrong? Get no specific error

Tags: java, sql, arrays

I want to insert data in a String array. But I get the error, that the code was suspended (for example in in this part: System.out.println("What is the name of the table? ");

But why?
Here is the rest of the code.

```
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
private static String tabName = "";
private static int tabSpaltenAnz = 0;
private static String[] spaltenName = new String[tabSpaltenAnz];

public static void abfrageTabellenInformationen()   {

    System.out.println("What is the name of the table? ");
    tabName = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("How many columns?");
    tabSpaltenAnz = input.nextInt();

    for(int i = 1; i <= tabSpaltenAnz; i++) {

        int k = 0;

        System.out.println("Insert name, data type and constraint for the  " + 
        i + ".  column.");

        String eingabeSpaltenAnz = input.nextLine();
        spaltenName[k] = eingabeSpaltenAnz;

        k++;
    }

}
```

Comment: how are you running that?? where is the main method???

Comment: "But I get the error, that the code was suspended" - can you include the full stack trace of the error that you are seeing?

Comment: What do you mean by you "get the error, that the code was suspended"?

Comment: k will always be 0...

Comment: hi, i get this as error:

Datenbank [Java Application] 
 Datenbank at localhost:49774 
  Thread [main] (Suspended) 
   TabelleErstellen.abfrageTabellenInformationen() line: 15 
   Datenbank.StartAusgabe() line: 24 
   Datenbank.main(String[]) line: 40 
 C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin\javaw.exe (22.06.2016, 18:03:28)

Answer (score 0):

The array  spaltenName is always going to be size 0.  You should put `spaltenName = new String[tabSpaltenAnz];` after `tabSpaltenAnz = input.nextInt();` in the method.

You also do not need the variable `k`.  You can replace `k` with `i`, start `i` at 0 in the for loop and make your output statement `System.out.println("Insert name, data type and constraint for the  " + i+1 + ".  column.");`

Comment: Aaaaah sure, but how to use this array in other methods, when it is no static class array?

Comment: If you are in the same class and want to access the array, you just need to declare it as private or public and declare it outside of any method.  If you wanted to access that specific variable in another class then you can declare it as static.